# How to change the colour of <a> of a main menu item, when submenu item is hovered

Tags: html, css

I hope someone can help me. **[Here is a site](http://joomlademo.klea.internetshop.cc)** I want to built.

I wanted the menu to stay blue, when I go to the submenu. And I succeeded with it. It stays blue thanks to this code:

```
nav li.active.parent > a, nav li:hover > a {
background-image: url(http://horyzon.de/images/images/navbg.png);
}
```

But I can't make the text to stay #FFF, as soon as the mouse goes to the submenu.
Can anyone produce the solution to this? Thousand thanks in advance.

This screenshot explains what I mean:

[image]

Comment: You should post a fiddle for this. http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

I could be missing something here as I haven't actually seen your markup, (no offense but I'm not visiting your site to look for it) but you could update your CSS to something like this:

```
nav li.active.parent > a, nav li:hover > a {
  background-image: url(http://horyzon.de/images/images/navbg.png);
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is the solution.

To be honest. I had already tried "color: #fff!important;" but for some unexplainable reason it did not work. Now I cleaned up the code down under, and suddenly it works. weird

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
nav li:hover a,
nav li:hover a span {
  color: #fff;
}
```

I hope this helps. You want to stay away from being "too" specific such as `nav.main-nav li.parent > a.active`.

You want to be a little more modular like so: `nav li:hover a`; however, I can sometime understand that it won't work, so you need to look at how it's already behaving prior to your modifications.

Then again, it really depends on the situation.